# Easy way to learn data structures and algorithm

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to learn data structures/link lists using c/c++ to start a career in software programming...but the complexity is too much for a beginner level.

My question here is:

1. Is there an easy way of learning data structures/link lists ?
2. Is C/C++ really suited for learning of data structures ?
3. In the industry, which language do they use for implementing DS?

Comment: *"In industry"* - which industry? There is no one "software programming" industry, there's a lot of different specializations and a lot of different companies, not all of them use the same programming language

Comment: There's no easy way to learn linked lists. Lot's of people struggle, just keep practising. C and C++ are good languages to learn about data structures, but so are lots of other languages. It might be that you would find a different language easier.

Comment: Also knowing how to implement a linked list is only a small part of being a productive programmer. You could say that know how to use a linked list is more important, because someone will always have implemented the linked list for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is common to see other languages using C/C++ for low-level implementations of data structures and algorithms, it doesn't mean that it is the ***easiest*** way to learn about them.

You need to keep in mind that when you are talking about data-structures, there are two levels we use:

1. ***Abstract Data Type*** (or ADT) which defines the expected behavior (or an abstract API) of a data structure - it is **not implementation depended**. For example, the most basic ADT is [List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)).
2. ***Implementation*** of a certain ADT - for example, Linked-List is an **implementation** of the ADT named List. It can also be used as an implementation of Queue and Stack. So is array - it can implement all of the above, and can implement the ADT Heap and Priority-Heap (even though, in some regards there are better implementations for that!).

You should start by learning and understanding the **theory** behind data-structures - the different ADT, and when do we use each. Then start exploring the different ***theoretical*** implementations of those, and only ***then*** start working on implementing data-structures on your own!

In fact, in most DS courses that I know, coding is a very minor part of the assignments, and I have implemented only WAVL Tree (an implementation of self-balancing binary search tree, similar to Red-Black Tree) and Fibonnaci-Heap in the entire class, using ***Java***.

The most famous book in this field is [Intro to Algorithms / CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms), and most courses are based on it.

P.S If you will look at implementations of data-structures in C/C++, it can become very overwhelming, so avoid specific implementations - it is more important the higher-level of the implementations.